# Django: Override user queryset to filter out admin/staff users from the public?

Tags: python, django, server, django-rest-framework, backend

I want to filter the user manager self.get_queryset() method in such a way that users on the client application don't see admin and staff users when searching for or viewing other accounts. The issue I'm running into is I am unable to login with my auth system if I override get_queryset entirely. My current setup is:

```
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def get_public_queryset(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(active=True, verified=True, admin=False, staff=False)
```

Using this design works fine if I define various sorting methods in the manager (because I can simply call that method), but it seems as though there should be a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think additional methods, as you've implemented is good a solution, but if you insist using get_queryset method it would be fine to override the method and preserve base functionality. I'd do something like this:

```
...
def get_queryset(self, *a, **kw):
    queryset = super().get_queryset(*a, **kw)
    # filter your queryset here as you wish
    queryset = queryset.filter(active=True, verified=True, admin=False, staff=False)
    return queryset
...
```

As I've spotted from question text, you tried to call self.get_queryset() which would be recursive call (not super class implementation call), which will finally cause maximum recursion depth exceeded error.

Hope it helps